# rails 3 routing to root my app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, url, routes, root

I my root url of my app is **home/index**, but if I'll click on link for root of my app, I have in body of that link **:controller => 'home', :action => 'home'** - and that means, that after click on this link I'll redirect to root and url address I'll have **myapp.com/home/index**. 
And I would like to have there only **myapp.com**.

I am looking to solution and I found **root_url** -- but if I'll use this helper,

```
<%= link_to 'Back to root', :root_url %>
```

I'll get an error **undefined method `root_url_path'** -- I would like to ask you, how is possible to define this helper, what everything is need for using this helper?

Thank you and nice a rest of weekend :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
<%= link_to 'Back to root', root_url %>
```

... `root_url` should be a method call and not a symbol

Comment: uff... I am blushing for this stupid mistake, I should go to sleep :)
Thanks Jits.

Comment: No problem... it happens to the best of us :)

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there, though it's not `:root_url`, just `:root`

```
<%= link_to 'Back to root', :root %>
```